# Interface Design to Handle Different Messages sent by the Publisher/Server Compile Error

Tags: c#, .net, interface

I am looking for generic pattern, best practice where I can get a handler for each kind of message that a server sends to the client.

Let me explain the scenario, and provide some code to explain some questions that might arise.

1. I have three kinds of messages(all derive from same base class MessageBase) that  the server can send to the client. Lets say the three message types are

   - One
   - Two
   - Three

     2. Once the client gets this message(`MessageBase`) it needs the appropriate handler to handle the message which is done in the Interface (`IGetMessageHandler<MessageBase>`, see code example below) base on the `MessageType`(One,two or three)
     3. All Message Handlers implement interface `IHandleMessage<T>` (where T is concrete message i.e. One,Two or Three)
     4. The issue I am facing is that the `GetHandler` in interlace defined above in point "2" above fails  compilation that it cannot convert a concrete `class(HandleMessageOne:IHadleMessage<MessageOne>)` to `IHandleMessage<BaseMessage>`

Questions: Why ?and How to solve(better design)

Example

`enum MessageType{One,Two,Three}
    public abstract class BaseMessage
    {
      public MessageType   MsgType{get;set;}

    }`

lets say there are three derived classes from BaseMessage and call them MessageOne,MessageTwo,MessageThree

```
 `   public interface IGetMessageHandler<T> where T:BaseMessage
{
  IHandleMessage<T>Gethandler(); // return handler based on 
}`

**`public class GetMessageHandler : IGetMessageHandler
{
   public IHandleMessage<T>Gethandler(BaseMessage msg)
   {
          switch(msg.Type)
          {
                case MessageType.One: return new HandleMessageOne();
case MessageType.Two: return new HandleMessageTwo();
case MessageType.Three: return new HandleMessageThree();
          }
   }`**
```

*Issue: Above does not compile saying that it cannot conert from 
HandleMessageOne to IHandleMessage*

```
`public interfce IHandleMessage<T> where T:BaseMessage
{
  void Handle(T msg); // do some stuff
}
public class HandleMessageOne:IHandleMessage<MessageOne>{
 void Handle(MessageOne msg){//do something}
}
public class HandleMessageTwo:IHandleMessage<MessageTwo>{ 
 void Handle(MessageTwo msg){//do something}
}
public class HandleMessageThree:IHandleMessage<MessageThree>{
 void Handle(MessageThree msg){//do something}
}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you be losing anything by removing all the generics and just cast to the appropriate type in each of the handlers?

```
public interface IHandleMessage
{
    void Handle(BaseMessage msg);
}

public class HandleMessageOne:IHandleMessage
{
    void Handle(BaseMessage msg)
    {
        var msgOne = msg as MessageOne;
        // do something with msgOne...
    }
}
// etc...
```

Comment: I wanted to use generics to provide a framework for the team to use. I impleneted a hybrid using your and Steve's approach

Answer (score 1):

You can try making the IHandleMessage interface non-generic and handle BaseMessage. Then make an abstract base class that takes a BaseMessage and casts it to the specific type and calls an overloaded Handle on the child class. Consider something like this:

```
public interface IHandleMessage {
    void Handle(BaseMessage msg);
}

public abstract class HandleBase<T> : IHandleMessage where T : BaseMessage {
    public void Handle(BaseMessage msg) {
        Handle((T)msg);
    }

    public abstract void Handle(T t);
}

public class HandleMessageOne : HandleBase<MessageOne> {
    public override void Handle(MessageOne message) {
        // do work
    }
}

public class GetMessageHandler {
    public IHandleMessage GetHandler(BaseMessage msg) {
        switch(msg.Type) {
            case MessageType.One: return new HandleMessageOne();
            case MessageType.Two: return new HandleMessageTwo();
            case MessageType.Three: return new HandleMessageThree();
        }
    }
}
```